# why is my uilabel in ios 10 not expanding?

Tags: ios, uilabel, ios-autolayout

I am using a ui label in ios the snapshots of whose constraints along with the label adjacent horizontally to it I am attaching. I expect both the labels to expand dynamically based on the text assigned to them dynamically and be of equal heights but they are not expanding.Why?

[image: 1]

Comment: I can see that you have a fixed width there. Delete the Width Equals: 105

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured that out myself. Its just a bug in the xcode that was causing the issue. Xcode behaviour is inconsistent at times.